# Why t-stat is normally reported but not p-value?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, p-value, inference

I just wonder why t-stat is normally reported with an asterisk to indicate significance but not p-value.

Comment: Reporting of results differs from person to person. Different publications also demand results be reported in their own style, so authors are sometimes chained to the set way. If you see something like that, you're probably seeing a specific style, not the reasoning for which p-values are usually reported.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I think you should make this an answer rather than a comment (and +1)

Comment: "normally" depends very much on which area you're publishing in. Some journals you'll not see an asterisk, but you'll see plenty of p-values.

Comment: Given the t-statistic, the p-values are redundant. Omitting p-values allows you to state essentially the same information and conserve column space for further details or simply parsimony.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is that, with the p-value, it is trivial to see the significance levels at which the hypothesis is and is not rejected (that is why it is also called marginal significance level!): if your p-value is 0.0867, it would really be an overkill to add an asterix to indicate that the null is rejected at the 10%-level.

When your t-statistic is, say, 1.78, you may or may not see directly whether that implies rejection at the 10% level (and even less so with statistics that are, say, $\chi^2$, $F$-distributed etc.).